# MongoDB MongoClient.GetServer() is Deprecated. What is the new API?

Tags: c#, mongodb

This is my connection string to my database:

```
private static string ConnectionString = "mongodb://user:password@server:port/";
private static string AuthSource = "?authSource=location";

public static MongoCollection<ItemEntity> GetMyItemCollectionDB = new MongoClient(ConnectionString + DBName + AuthSource)
.GetServer().GetDatabase(DBName).GetCollection<ItemEntity>(CollectionName);
```

I heard that you can drop the `getserver` method:

```
public static MongoCollection<ItemEntity> GetMyItemCollectionDB = new MongoClient(ConnectionString + DBName + AuthSource)
  .GetDatabase(DBName)
  .GetCollection<ItemEntity>(CollectionName) as MongoCollection<ItemEntity>;
```

But for that, I get a "null object" error. What's the problem?

**EDIT**: If it is not that important to use the new API, then just tell me.

Comment: Your GetMyItemCollectionDB method does an awful lot.... which bit is returning null

Comment: Well, the first one works.. I don't understand why the second one is not working. Can you explain why? and the possible solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the MongoServer Instance, I de-compile assembly MongoDB.Driver.dll,
The function GetServer is

```
[Obsolete("Use the new API instead.")]
public static MongoServer GetServer(this MongoClient client)
{
    return 
MongoServer.Create(MongoServerSettings.FromClientSettings(client.Settings));
}
```

So you can try following code

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(ConnectionString + DBName + AuthSource);
MongoServer server =  new MongoServer(MongoServerSettings.FromClientSettings(client.Settings));
var yourCollection = server.GetDatabase(DBName).GetCollection<ItemEntity>(CollectionName);
```

There're 4 ways in version 2.0.0+

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.Create(MongoServerSettings)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.WithReadConcern(ReadConcern)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.WithReadPreference(ReadPreference)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.WithWriteConcern(WriteConcern)
```

Comment: It would really make your answer more useful if you could expand it (elaborate).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you know your second code at last returns an `IMongoCollection<ItemEntity>`

However, `MongoCollection` doesn't inherit from `IMongoCollection`, that's why you get a `NULL` value in the end.